# Alas, is it informal or formal? Can it be used in formal writing?

Tags: formality

Question title is enough. Can I use **alas** in formal writing , especially in scientific writing?

I do not remember seeing it a lot in scientific articles but dictionary references does not say anything about it informal.

Comment: You will not see *alas* often in formal writing. *Alas* is antiquated, and used with knowledge that it is informally a bit ironic/sarcastic/anachronistic. Scholarly writing is not usually supposed to embrace these qualities.

Comment: Alas, no, you will not see it in formal writing.

Comment: In my view it is a perfectly good expression, in modern use, though perhaps more by the literate and artistic. But I am just wondering how one might wish to use it in scientific writing. Perhaps in a mathematical proof... 'Alas, it cannot be a right angle as the square on the hypotenuse does not equal that on the other two sides!'

Comment: I use "Alas" as "at last" as contraction, "although" instead of Albeit, "go forth" instead of Avast, then see the looks of people's faces!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's neither formal nor informal.  It's a word.

As to its usage, it is a fairly old-fashioned sounding word. The usage has been in steady decline since the 19th century (according to the graph in the Google definition).

As a general rule, you can use this word in scientific writing, but I don't know that you would want to.   Scientific writing doesn't lend itself to the emotional handwringing that alas conveys.

> Alas, the data did not support the conclusion.

vs

> The data did not support the conclusion.

The first introduces a strange sense of emotion to the analysis. The second reports the facts in an appropriately sterile manner.

I think the big picture is that emotional assessments play little role in proper scientific writing.  Even in the conclusion, I think the word unfortunately would be more appropriate.

> Unfortunately, we were unable to power the study to determine the specificity of this outcome.

Comment: "We, the authors of this paper wept many bitter tears that the data did not fully support our researches...."

Comment: @Oldcat "After which two of our junior members ritually disemboweled themselves ..."

Answer (score 4):

Though alas is a formal adverb, I' d rather use 'unfortunately' in a scientific article.

Comment: Jinx!  You owe me a coke!